# OpenXML remove bullets or numbers from Word

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml

I have a web app where I generate a Word document. I use merge fields to insert data from SQL. I have marked one of the merge fields as a bulleted list, so that when I insert data, I could split it up and using Append(Break), I can create a bulleted list. This works great! The problem is that sometimes, I don't have anything to put in the merge field so I just say `Field.Text = ""`. Thus I remove all the `<<MergeFieldName>>` from the word document.

But the bullet or number still remains in the document. I don't know how to remove it. I tried going up the hierarchy like: Txt -> Run -> Paragraph -> ParagraphProperties -> NumberingProperties -> NumberingID/LvlReference...but I don't know what to do next. I'm sure I need to do a `Remove()` somewhere but I don't know where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I managed to achieve the result by going up the hierarchy and setting the numberingId.Val to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using openXML SDK I was able to remove numbering and indention the document.
This is how I did it.

```
var number = container.Descendants<NumberingProperties>().FirstOrDefault();
if (number != null)
{
    number.Parent.Descendants<ParagraphStyleId>().FirstOrDefault().Remove();
    number.Parent.Descendants<Indentation>().FirstOrDefault().Left = "-45";
    number.Remove();
}
```

container is `OpenXmlCompositeElement`, you can get this object from something like this `OpenXmlCompositeElement container = tagElement.Descendants<SdtContentRun>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: What is "container"?